# Display minimum value in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Doing a program exercise to display the minimum value from the first three textboxes into the fourth. When I enter value and hit the button no result pops up in the fourth textbox but Visual Studio also doesn't give me any errors. What mistakes have I made?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim First As Double = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Second As Double = TextBox2.Text
        Dim Third As Double = TextBox3.Text

        If First < Second Then
        ElseIf First < Third Then
            TextBox4.Text = First
        End If

        If Second < First Then
        ElseIf Second < Third Then
            TextBox4.Text = Second
        End If

        If Third < First Then
        ElseIf Third < Second Then
            TextBox4.Text = Third

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm still using vb6, but seeing your codes, I see that after codes : If First > Second Then you add ElseIf. It should be statement  not condition

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent [the wheel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcd487wd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TextBox4.Text = Math.Min(Math.Min(First, Second), Third)
```

---

Regarding your original code: You probably meant to write

```
If A AndAlso B Then
```

instead of

```
If A Then
    ' Do Nothing
ElseIf B Then     ' Means: If (Not A) And B
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try like this:

```
If First > Second Then
   If First > Third Then
      TextBox4.Text = First
   End If
End If

If Second > First Then
   If Second > Third Then
      TextBox4.Text = Second
   End If
End If

If Third > First Then
   If Third > Second Then
      TextBox4.Text = Third
   End If
End If
```

So, the formula is:

```
If -> condition - > statement
```